# Image file upload on shared hosting failing in laravel application

Tags: laravel, file-upload, shared-hosting

When i am uploading a file(users profile image), my code works fine on local machine(windows). The file is being uploaded on `uploads\profile\avatar\` folder.

But then i deployed my project on a shared hosting(linux). Now my file upload fails. Instead of moving the uploaded file to `uploads\profile\avatar\` folder, a new folder with the name `uploads\profile\avatar\` is being crated inside the **public_html** directory(on the same level as the `uploads` directory).

**EDIT**

Below are the lines that does the moving of uploaded files:

`avatar_directory = 'uploads\profile\avatar\\';
$avatar_image = $request->{'profile-avatar'};
$avatar_new_name = 'profile'.$user->id.'_'.date('Y-m-d_H-i-s', time()).'_'.$avatar_image->getClientOriginalName();`

How do i take care of this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

To create a relative path one level up use `../`

```
../uploads/profile/avatar/
```

`../` will put you at 1 level above public, which is the webroot (I presume)

make sure uploads/profile/avatar/ exists and is writable

Comment: Won't this look for the `uploads` folder on the same level as the public_html? whereas my uploads folder is inside public_html. Instead of moving the uploaded file to this folder laravel is creating another folder with name `uploads\profile\avatar`. I mean the name of the newly created folder includes the backslashes. I have added to the original question the lines that does the renaming and moving. Please check the edited question. This code works perfectly on local machine!

Answer (score 0):

Well i found the issue.

Thing is my local development server was windows but the shared hosting was Linux.
In my code i was using windows like syntax to define the destination directory:

```
$avatar_directory = 'uploads\profile\avatar\\';
```

Linux was not able to find this directory due to the backslashes. So i changed all the back-slashes to forward-slashes and that fixed it:

```
$avatar_directory = 'uploads/profile/avatar/';
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: To be OS independent with such a code, use PHP's `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead. I.E. `$avatar_directory = 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'profile' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'avatar' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;`